# Problem with the Edit and Delete for my Forum page

Tags: php, mysql

My code is not appropriately editing or deleting my comments. I put my code through a syntax checker and that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have tried going through all the articles I could find and even tried multiple different methods but nothing seems to be working.
The issue is that I keep getting this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\FinalSite\edit.php on line 5
```

and when I click on edit the boxes will be filled with text like
Title:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\FinalSite\edit.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

and Comment:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\FinalSite\edit.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
```

I have tried multiple different ways to define id but to no avail. I have looked and implemented all the solutions I could find on StackOverflow but with no luck.

This is what I used to create the comments table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `content` text NOT NULL,
       `submit_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my code:

```
//This is the comments.php:
<?php
// Update the details below with your MySQL details
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'database_name';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DATABASE_NAME . ';charset=utf8', $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error
    exit('Failed to connect to database!');
}
// Below function will convert datetime to time elapsed string
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);
    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
    $string = array('y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'w' => 'week', 'd' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour', 'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second');
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }
    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
// This function will populate the comments and comments replies using a loop
function show_comments($comments, $parent_id = -1) {
    $html = '';
    if ($parent_id != -1) {
        // If the comments are replies sort them by the "submit_date" column
        array_multisort(array_column($comments, 'submit_date'), SORT_ASC, $comments);
    }
    // Iterate the comments using the foreach loop
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        if ($comment['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            // Add the comment to the $html variable
            $html .= '
            <div class="comment">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="name">' . htmlspecialchars($comment['name'], ENT_QUOTES) . '</h3>
                    <span class="date">' . time_elapsed_string($comment['submit_date']) . '</span>
                </div>
                <p class="content">' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comment['content'], ENT_QUOTES)) . '</p>
                <a class="reply_comment_btn" href="#" data-comment-id="' . $comment['id'] . '">Reply</a>
                <a href=edit.php>edit</a>
                <a href=delete_confirm.php>delete</a>
                ' . show_write_comment_form($comment['id']) . '
                <div class="replies">
                ' . show_comments($comments, $comment['id']) . '
                </div>
            </div>
            ';
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
// This function is the template for the write comment form
function show_write_comment_form($parent_id = -1) {
    $html = '
    <div class="write_comment" data-comment-id="' . $parent_id . '">
        <form>
            <input name="parent_id" type="hidden" value="' . $parent_id . '">
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            <textarea name="content" placeholder="Write your comment here..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    ';
    return $html;
}
// Page ID needs to exist, this is used to determine which comments are for which page
if (isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    // Check if the submitted form variables exist
    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['content'])) {
        // POST variables exist, insert a new comment into the MySQL comments table (user submitted form)
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comments (page_id, parent_id, name, content, submit_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->execute([ $_GET['page_id'], $_POST['parent_id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['content'], date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ]);
        exit('Your comment has been submitted! Please reload the page to view your comment.');
    }
    // Get all comments by the Page ID ordered by the submit date
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page_id = ? ORDER BY submit_date DESC');
    $stmt->execute([ $_GET['page_id'] ]);
    $comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Get the total number of comments
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comments FROM comments WHERE page_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([ $_GET['page_id'] ]);
    $comments_info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}

 else {
    exit('No page ID specified!');
}
?>
<div class="comment_header">
    <span class="total"><?=$comments_info['total_comments']?> comments</span>
    <a href="#" class="write_comment_btn" data-comment-id="-1">Write Comment</a>
</div>
<?php
if($_SESSION['is_open'] = TRUE){
    echo show_write_comment_form();
}else{
    echo "Please login to post.";
    echo "</br>";
}
if($_SESSION['is_open'] = TRUE){
    echo show_comments($comments);
}else{
    echo "Please login to see others comments.";
}
?>
```

```
//This is the edit.php:
<?php 
// connect to SQL
require_once('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
#data preparation for the query
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);

# selects title and description fields from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id= '$'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_connect_error());        
# retrieved by using $row['col_name']
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>

<h3>Edit</h3>
<form action=<?="save_edit.php?id='$id'"?>enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="myForm" >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Title</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="70" maxlength="100" name="name" value="<?php $row['name'] ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Description</b></td>
      <td><textarea cols="80" rows="18" name="content"><?php $row['content']; ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $id; ?>" />
  <input name="enter" type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

```
//This is the save_edit.php:
<?php
require_once('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
#data preparation for the query
$id = intval($_POST["id"]);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

$sql = "UPDATE comments SET 
        name='$_POST[name]', 
        content='$_POST[content]', 
        WHERE id=$id";

if (mysqli_error()) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
header ("location: index.html");
?>
```

```
//This is the delete.php:
<?php
require_once('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
$id = $_GET['comments_id'];
if($_SESSION['is_open'] = TRUE) {
    session_start();
    echo "Welcome | " . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "!";
    $query = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if($result){
        echo "<br>The selected comment has been deleted.";
    } else{
        echo"<br>The selected comment could not be deleted.";
    }
}else {
    echo "login please";
       header("Location: login.php");
}
echo "<p><a href=index.html>Go back to the main page</a></p>";
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

If you are wondering about the is_open that is how I confirm that the user is logged in before allowing them to access the forum.

Comment: When you're doing `$id = intval($_GET["id"]);`, there is no `$_GET['id']`. You also seem to have a typo on your select. Shouldn't `WHERE id= '$'` be `WHERE id= '$id'`? And because of that typo, `mysqli_fetch_array($result);` will return `null`, which is the reason why `<?php $row['name'] ?>` throws an error. Also, you're not echoing the value. It should be `<?php echo $row['name'] ?>`. That's just a few issues.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a step back and do one thing at the time and do some basic debugging. There are currently too many issues all over the place atm.

Answer (score -1):

In your "save_edit.php" file you are not doing anything with the SQL query. With mysqli should look something like this: $dbc->query($sql)

Comment: That's just one of many many issues with their code and it doesn't account for their error messages.